# Java algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm

I am a server side Java programmer. In my recent job search, I have come across a few postings where they mention : ' Candidates with expereince in algorithm development will be preferred'. What exactly does this refer to? This is the posting for a Bank...so not a job for a research laboratory...just to clarify a bit.
I asked my headhunter ...he does not have an idea about this.
When we use Java in applications, we use the APIs that implement algorithms...so technically we are not developing algorithms. Right?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Algorithm development" sounds vague. Maybe the original technical requirement was knowledge of algorithms, and somewhere along the way, someone thought it didn't sound impressive enough, and rewrote it to "candidates with experience in algorithm development will be preferred".

I don't think it means "the ability to create new algorithms from scratch". Rather, you need to be able to recognize when a program could benefit from the use of some known algorithm or data structure, or a slight modification of one, and the ability to get that done. This is a crucial skill on many projects, and especially those where speed is important.

The generic algorithms provided by the Java class library (like `Arrays.sort`) make up a small fraction of what you might find in even [an introductory algorithms textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937). (I'm not a Java hacker by trade, but is there even a heap sort?)

Answer (score 1):

Wrong.

Well, of course it depends on the project.  But there are plenty of mundane projects that need more than just sticking tab A into slot B.  If you like, consider that they said "algorithm development", not "algorithm research".  Research and development are two parts of of the deal -- related but not the same.

Not every algorithm is available as a standard library.  Also, a particular implementation of an algorithm is not necessarily appropriate for every application.  Finally, even when using a canned routine, understanding how the algorithm works is frequently helpful in figuring out how to use it properly.

So, the job postings are for someone with some understanding of algorithms.  How to use them.  How to adapt them to a particular purpose. How to read a paper (written by an egghead from a research laboratory, perhaps?) and implement the algorithm therein -- or to reject it and continue looking for something more suitable to the purpose at hand.  And, yes, very occasionally, how to come up with something new and different.